# Can't extract data from images using azure labelling tool

Tags: azure

I am trying to extract the data from images by using azure labelling tool. I am facing an error that while saving a project.

```
error encrypting data - crypto.[enter image description here][1]subtle is undefined
```

Comment: Isn't that obvious from the error ? you should fil the `[enter image description here]` with the appropriate value

Comment: it an pop up error while submitting the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the firefox won't supports for submitting the project in azure labelling tool

---

> Try with Microsoft edge or internet explorer
>   ***....
>   labelling tool wont support because its not secure thing